# Is this possible in CANopen?

Tags: canopen

I'm planning a CANopen network with a few nodes (8-9) so I'm thinking of the Node-ID using 4 bits, and 7 for the rest of the COB-ID to indicate more than the 4 basic PDOs there seems to be (as up to 512 PDO are possible, apparently). from the below table (source: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CANopen?msclkid=cc03ecf1cf8911ec8b496ce77ca22492#Predefined_Connection_Set[7]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CANopen?msclkid=cc03ecf1cf8911ec8b496ce77ca22492#Predefined_Connection_Set%5B7%5D))

[image]

I have the following questions:

1. Can I have my PDOs at 180 + NodeID , 190 + NodeID , 1A0 + NodeID , etc. as NodeID is 4 bits?
2. Do I have to have pairs of TPDO and RPDO or may I have an unequal number?
3. Same with SDOs, can I have different Transmit and Receive number of them?
4. Can I rearrange the Sync, Emgy, Timestamp and NMT COB-IDs to have more PDO/ SDO? Like Sync at 010, Timestamp at 020, NMT 030, etc. Or can I but better not, for whatever reason?
5. As an alternative to the above, could I map PDOs/ SDOs to COB-IDs like 010 + NodeId, etc?
6. What is LSS?

Comment: Node ID is 7 bits. Do not invent your own standard. (ps: You can make a device be multiple Nodes if you need more PDO's.)

Comment: Jeroen3, I'm aware of that, but the same CANopen spec also states that up to 512 PDO per node are possible, is that exclusively for 29-bit COB-ID extended CAN?

Comment: Jeroen3, so you would have 7-bit nodes XXXYYYY and I would have 4-bit nodes (YYYY) with their function codes extended by 3 bits (XXX), is there any practical difference?

Answer (score 1):

For my answers I'm assuming you're using CAN 2.0A, because otherwise your proposed 'hacks' wouldn't make any sense.

> 1. Can I have my PDOs at 180 + NodeID , 190 + NodeID , 1A0 + NodeID , etc. as NodeID is 4 bits?

Sure

"180 + NodeID, 200 + NodeID, ..., 500 + NodeID" are only default assignments.

You may use any of the following COB-IDs for TPDO and RPDO:

- 181 .. 1FF
- 201 .. 27F
- 281 .. 2FF
- 301 .. 37F
- 381 .. 3FF
- 401 .. 47F
- 481 .. 4FF
- 501 .. 57F

> 2. Do I have to have pairs of TPDO and RPDO or may I have an unequal number?

You can mix and match TPDOs and RPDOs as it fits your application.

You may map a TPDO to any number of RPDOs. And likewise any number of TPDOs to an RPDO.

> 3. Same with SDOs, can I have different Transmit and Receive number of them?

I'm not sure what you mean. Please clarify.

But essentially, an SDO request COB-ID (e.g. 601) is mapped to an SDO response COB-ID (e.g. 581).
The funtion code (bits 7 .. 10) defines the protocol type (e.g. NMT, SDO rx, SDO tx).

> 4. Can I rearrange the Sync, Emgy, Timestamp and NMT COB-IDs to have more PDO/ SDO? Like Sync at 010, Timestamp at 020, NMT 030, etc. Or can I but better not, for whatever reason?

No, that would be a violation of the CANopen standard.

You may define your own application layer on top of CAN. You just cannot call it CANopen if you do so.

> 5. As an alternative to the above, could I map PDOs/ SDOs to COB-IDs like 010 + NodeId, etc?

No.

> 6. What is LSS?

The Layer Settings Service are primarily used to configure NodeIDs and the CAN baudrate.